# Getting the size of a malloc'd memory chunk?

Tags: linux, malloc

Some Linux code is calling malloc in 100 places and I need to know how big any one chunk is. 
Normally I'd just record these sizes in a my_malloc function but I'm not allowed to do that in this instance. Is there any way to ask the malloc subsystem to provide chunk size for a malloc'd pointer?

Comment: A closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451104/how-to-get-memory-block-length-after-malloc

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use the [LD_PRELOAD trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859/how-could-i-intercept-linux-sys-calls/69884#69884) to intercept calls to malloc (definition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)).  You do not even need to recompile your source code.

Depending on what you are trying to discover, [Google Perftools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/) might be useful as well.

Comment: I had to google a bit to find out what the LD_PRELOAD trick _is_, please link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick in your answer too :)

Comment: @Kimvais: Well, I linked to sample code, figuring that is always better than a one-sentence definition :-).  OK I have also added a link to the other SO question.

Comment: thanks. I guess I'm just the kind of person who thinks _how does it work_ is much more interesting question than _what does it do_  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
*((size_t *)ptr - 1) & ~7
```

/me covers.

Comment: Ouch.  Not sure that will work on 64-bit systems.  And I am almost certain it will not work for a malloc() of more than 128k or so (for which glibc will use mmap).  But nice idea for a quick hack :-).

Comment: And seriously, `int` for a size? Jesus. `*((size_t *)ptr - 1) & ~8` at least.

Comment: Oh I get it... I would hate to run into this in some code somewhere.

Comment: That is *entirely* non-portable.  The language standard says nothing about how the malloc subsystem stores the sizes of allocated objects -- or even that it does so.  For example, `malloc(57)` might allocate 64 bytes and keep no record of the original size.  Or the size might not be stored explicitly at all, as long as there's enough information for `realloc` and `free` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that.

Comment: There is no *portable* way to do that, but a non-portable hack might be good enough if the goal is to debug a problem.