# How to know when to call delete and when delete[] in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, smart-pointers, delete-operator

I was implementing classes `my_unique_ptr` and `my_shared_ptr` that mimic the standard library smart pointers `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` to get to know it better.

When implementing the destructors I'm in this trouble to decide whether to use `delete` or `delete[]` to free the memory. As much as I read on SO and other sites, there is no *portable way* to know how many bytes were allotted by `new[]` (or whether `new` was used or `new[]`) ([How many bytes were allocated by new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524845/how-many-bytes-were-allocated-by-new))

While implementing class `my_unique_ptr` I have no way of knowing how many bytes the user will request from the constructor , i.e.

Whether he will do `my_unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int)`

or will he do
`my_unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int[5])`

If there is a way please let me know!

Here is my class (simplified and without cpy/move constructors):

```
template<typename ValueType>
class my_unique_ptr {

    ValueType *internal_ptr = nullptr;

public:
    
    // Default constructor
    my_unique_ptr() {
       internal_ptr = nullptr;
    }

    // Paramterized constructor
    explicit my_unique_ptr(ValueType *ptr) {
       if (ptr)
        internal_ptr = ptr;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~my_unique_ptr() {
       
        // How do I know whether to use
           delete ptr;

        // or
           delete[] ptr;
        
     }
```

I read somewhere that the compiler keeps track of the argument of `new[]` which is then used by `delete[]` to free the memory correctly. Also read that "It is the responsibility of the programmer to match `new` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete[]`". But how do I program this in my class so that it always matches the correct operators?

**Sidenote:**

Running `valgrind` while using `delete` everywhere instead of `delete[]` and passing more than 1 `int` (say with `new int[5]`) in my constructor, Valgrind says that all memory blocks were freed and there is no chance of leak! (although shows warnings like `mismatched new[] with delete`. Does this mean `delete` is successfully freeing all the 5 `ints` allocated by `new[]`? Please help.
I'm on `Ubuntu 18.04` and using `gcc 7.5.0`.

Comment: The simplest is to specialize `my_unique_ptr<T[]>` and then require users to use `my_unique_ptr<int[]> ptr1(new int[5]);`. This is what the standard library smart pointers do.

Comment: @cdhowie I understand now, thank you!

Comment: @cdhowie Its funny how everyone here is deleting their answer once you destroy them with your replies xD

Comment: @SirajQazi lol I got the similar reply, however, mine is also valid solution! So I will not delete that one..

Comment: @K.R.Park Haha sure, and thank you too for replying to my question :)

Comment: @SirajQazi Actually I didn't reply to any of the deleted answers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you can't know if a memory was allocated by `new` or `new[]`. But you can't even know that a memory stores an automatic duration object. E.g. your user can do:

```
int a = 24;

my_unique_ptr<int> ptr1(&a); // oups
```

There is no way for you to know that. So do what the standard library does:

- make a specialization for array types, e.g. `template <class T> class my_unique_ptr<T[]>` that calls `delete[]` on the destructor.
- It is a requirement that `my_unique_ptr<T>` must be initialized with a memory obtained from `new` and `my_unique_ptr<T[]>` must be initialized with a memory obtained from `new[]`. This is a contract the users of your library must respect. If it's not respected then it's UB.
- help the users respect this contract by providing equivalents of [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). Also see [Advantages of using std::make_unique over new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514509/advantages-of-using-stdmake-unique-over-new-operator)

---

> Does this mean delete is successfully freeing all the 5 ints allocated by new[]

No. Calling `delete` on a memory not obtained from `new` is UB.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for clearing this! I guess I didn't think of the possibility of another template specialization with `<T[]>` and so I wasn't getting how the compiler could possibly get the operators correctly matched. Thank you so much again :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, standard library smart pointers have extra facility than your code that they are able to take what operator(delete or delete[]) to use when their destructor is called. They take delete by default, and if you want to use delete[], you should provide it to the smart pointer constructor. Other than that, if you create a single object, use new and delete. if you create an array, use new[] for it, and delete[] for deleting it.

Comment: You don't have to use a custom deleter at all, just use e.g. `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`. There is a specialization for `T[]` that uses `delete[]`.

Comment: @cdhowie I was completely unaware of this kind of solution. A good point to learn. Thank you.