# How and where is variable type information stored?

Tags: c, pointers, types

If I have allocated memory for an int, I will (usually) be given 4 bytes. As I understand, these 4 bytes make up the entire footprint of this variable in memory.

Furthermore, if I have a pointer to this int, it will hold the address of the first of its 4 bytes.

However, how does my program know that the type of data in those 4 bytes consists of a single int? And since my pointer only holds this address, which supposedly only holds raw data, how does it know that whenever the address it holds is dereferenced, it should be interpreted as an int?

Where is this type information, and how and when does the program access it?

Comment: `it should be interpreted as an int`..well, that's why it's an `int *`, not `char *` or `float *`

Comment: The information is in the source code, and the compiler generates the machine code to respect the specification in the source code.  It is the compiler's job to get the access right.

Comment: It's not stored anywhere in the compiled program. It's the compiler that handles it.

Comment: it may be needed in weakly typed languages but not in a strongly typed language like C

Comment: I'm guessing that you might also be interested in the size of malloc'd block: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21185118/880584

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you compile a C program, the type information is essentially lost (or put another way, it is no longer needed).  This is because the interpretation of any bytes of memory in C are up to the code which reads them.  You can read a four-byte `int` as a `char[4]` with no problems, for example.

Type information may be preserved in certain cases for special reasons, such as debugging.  But this is stored in platform-specific formats (e.g. DWARF on Linux), and is not part of the C standard at all.